# Floating point number format

Tags: php, floating-point, number-formatting

I want to use `number_format` function in PHP. For example:

```
$number = 234.51;
echo number_format($number,2);
```

This works for float numbers but I want to use it for different numbers. If a number is decimal and doesn't have any floating points, it shows like : 145.00 . How can I fix this? I mean I want to show as many floating points as needed, not more.

Comment: Have you tried using round() instead of number_format()?

Comment: In my understanding, number_format should only be used for the display purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I can't get what I want from number_format so I did this and it works fine :

```
 public function floatNumber($number)
 {
      $number_array = explode('.', $number);
      $left = $number_array[0];
      $right = $number_array[1];
      return number_format($number, strlen($right));
 }
```

thanx all for your replies.

Comment: You could shorten that and write: `list($left, $right) = explode('.', $number, 2);`.

Comment: No, you can't because if `$number` is in fact an int, there will be no index 1 in the array (the decimal part). We should use `$right = $number_array[1] ?? '';` and `$left` can be deleted as it isn't used at all.

Answer (score 11):

Investigate the `printf` and `sprintf` functions instead of `number_format`.

They give the ability to format numbers as you wish.

```
printf("%d", $int)
```

would be appropriate for a decimal integer.

```
printf("%4.2f", $float)
```

would be appropriate for a floating point number with two decimal places.

`number_format` seems to be intended for internationalisation of currency output, but I don't think that's what you want because you mentioned decimal 'whole' numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a better way to do this, but you can compare the type, like the code below:

```
$number = 234.159;
if(is_float($number)) {
 echo number_format($number, 2);
}else {
 echo $number;
}
```

Comment: I believe the is the preferred way if you don't need to print this.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it's a bit quick and dirty, you could simply do a...

```
str_replace('.00', '', number_format($potentialFloat, 2));
```

Far from ideal, but effective.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key problem is defining how many positions are needed. Would you define 13.01 as 13 because the first decimal was a 0? Since printf and number format needs you to know how many decimals, I don't know that that would work for you.

Maybe something like this (which is a lot of functions, but looks for the first 0, and then returns the truncated string). Yes, it is intensive, but it may be the best way for you.

```
function show_number($number, $max = 8){
  if(strpos($number, '.')){
    $decimal = strpos($number, '.');
    if(strpos($number, '.0')){
      return substr($number, 0, $decimal);//returns whole if zero is first
    } else {
      if(strpos(substr($number, $decimal, $max), '0')){
        $zero = strpos(substr($number, $decimal, $max), '0');
        return substr($number, 0, $decimal+$zero);//returns number w/0 first zero
      } else {
        return substr($number, 0, $decimal+$max+1); //returns number with max places
      }
    }
  } else {
    return $number; //returns number if no decimals
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to get rid of trailing zeros:

```
// Trims a floating point number so there are no trailing zeros. For example:
// 1.00 -> 1
// 1.10 -> 1.1
function trimFloatingPoint($input) {
    $strNum = strval($input);

    while(substr($strNum, -1, 1) == '0')
        $strNum = substr($strNum, 0, strlen($strNum) -1);

    // Trailing zeros are gone. How about the trailing period?
    if(substr($strNum, -1, 1) == '.')
        $strNum = substr($strNum, 0, strlen($strNum) -1);

    return $strNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = $x - floor($x)
```

will give you the right floating point...