# Need to convert the floating values to integer format below the condition in php

Tags: php, kohana-3.2

Need to convert the floating values to integer format below the condition

$val = 75.00 means the value must be show 75

$val = 75.50 means the values must be show 75.50

the floating points values .00 means no need to display otherwise will display with floating values.

is possible in php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating point number format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734233/floating-point-number-format)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$val = 75.00;
$value = explode(".", $val);
$decimal_value = substr($value[0], 0, 1);

if($decimal_value == "00"){
   $val = $value[0];
} else {
   $val = number_format($val, 2, '.', '');
}
echo $val;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$val + 0` does the trick.

```
echo 75.00 + 0; // 75
echo 75.50 + 0; // 75.5
```

Internally, this is equivalent to casting to float with (float)$val or floatval($val) but I find it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

(float) $val;

In finally use below the code.

$ans = (float)$val;

echo $ans;  means it working perfectly.